# Rspec headaches: configuration advice appreciated

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, rspec, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I can't for the life of me seem to set up rspec/capybara in a way that doesn't throw random errors from time to time.  My most common errors (but not consistent) are along the lines of:

```
An error occurred in an after hook
  ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Post with id=1
  occurred at [...]/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:341:in `find_one'
```

And a close second is anything related to expecting model objects that were created within the spec and then not found later. e.g. something like

```
Sorter should populate featured_posts with appropriate posts
Failure/Error: Sorter.top_4.map(&:id).should eq(([best_new_post, best_old_post] + new_posts.last(2).reverse).map(&:id))

   expected: [2, 1, 40, 38]
        got: []
```

These tests will always pass when I run them individually, and they don't always fail when I run them in the suite.  I'm assuming there is some sort of issue with threads and how the database is set up, but I can't seem to figure it out.

My `spec_helper.rb` is a hodgepodge of advice from various sources:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'spork'

Spork.prefork do
  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
  require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
  require 'rspec/rails'
  require 'rspec/autorun'
  require 'capybara/rspec'
  require 'capybara/email/rspec'
  include ApplicationHelper

  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

  include Warden::Test::Helpers
  Warden.test_mode!

  ActionController::Base.asset_host = "http://localhost:3000"

  RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

    config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
    config.use_transactional_examples = false #factoryGirl

    # From http://railsapps.github.io/tutorial-rails-devise-rspec-cucumber.html
    config.before(:suite) do
      DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
      DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
    end
    config.before(:each) { DatabaseCleaner.start }
    config.after(:each) { DatabaseCleaner.clean }
    #

    config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

    ## Setting up email helpers
    config.include MailerMacros
    config.before(:each) { reset_email }

    ## Setting up test and login helpers for Devise testing
    config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller
    config.extend ControllerMacros, type: :controller

    # From http://railscasts.com/episodes/413-fast-tests
    config.order = "random"

    config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods

    config.treat_symbols_as_metadata_keys_with_true_values = true
    config.filter_run focus: true
    config.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true

    config.filter_run_excluding :slow unless ENV["SLOW_SPECS"]

    config.before(:all) { DeferredGarbageCollection.start }
    config.after(:all) { DeferredGarbageCollection.reconsider }
  end
end

Spork.each_run do  
  Rails.cache.clear
  Warden.test_reset!
  FactoryGirl.reload
end
```

I've tried removing pieces to troubleshoot, but it's hard to gauge whether it hss solved anything since the errors are sporadic.

Is there anything here that stands out as an obvious reason for the errors above, or any advice on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Did you follow the installation/configuration instructions under https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit#usage?

Comment: I guess it's *possible* that your hook ordering is wonky, although I'd expect that config hooks fire after spec hooks.  Try putting in logging for each hook saying it fired, and then see if the order is screwy for 'missing' objects.

Comment: EDIT:  Just found [this Capybara issue](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/1089) which may shed some light on things

Comment: @PeterAlfvin, I'm using selenium instead of capybara-webkit. I just switched to webkit to test it out, and it's having trouble finding and interacting with elements that are displayed via javascript (e.g. forms in a modal). I'll keep tweaking and see if I can get it working with capybara-webkit.

Comment: @DylanLacey thanks for the link. I'll look into whether it's ajax-related or not. If it is, I can try to mess with the way its finding and make sure that request finishes before the spec is done.

Comment: OK, the issue does not appear to be selenium or capybara-webkit specific. I've tried with both and I still get `An error occurred in an after hook` sporadically.

Comment: I've been having a similar problem using poltergeist.

Answer (score 1):

In your spec_helper.rb, try setting

```
config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
```

Comment: I went ahead and gave that a shot -- it threw all kinds of errors during the webdriver/js portions.  What is your thinking here?